# Java unreachable linked list branch garbage collection

Tags: java, linked-list, garbage-collection

I have a 'disfigured' linked list which has the following structure:

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> E
          ^
          |
          G
          ^
          |
          F
```

Suppose I have a reference pointing to A and a reference pointing to F. I want the branch `F->G` to be deleted from memory.

> Is it enough to set the reference to F as null and rely on GC to
>   remove the branch from memory?

Comment: @Michael `C` wouldn't be able to hold a "doubled" link to `B` and `G` together, so it must be singly-linked.

Comment: It's not a doubly linked list.

Comment: @Michael, By naturally go out of scope you mean that if i pass around the linked list head reference from one method to another the GC will eventually remove the branch from memory, right?

Comment: I think what I said may be confusing, so allow me to rephrase. You shouldn't use `foo = null` as a substitute for, for example, C++'s `delete foo`. As you're implementing a data structure that relies on `null` to indicate the end of a path it's okay to use it but don't think of it as deleting anything from memory. Think of it as mutating your data structure. *Yes* the objects *will* be garbage collected at some point but you're thinking in the wrong mindset for Java if you think of assigning null as "deleting" them.